# Why the last active link does nothing?

Tags: support, last-activity

E.g. in this question [VAO and element array buffer state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973690/vao-and-element-array-buffer-state?lastactivity) the last activity link just reloads the page. Is that supposed to happen? I realize that SO is evolving, so I was wondering if that might be a new bug or some old functionality not supported anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because 4 days ago the question [was edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8973690/revisions) by you. If the last activity was in the question (bounty started, question edited, reopened, or poked by Community user (maybe etc (but I am not sure (ask Shadow Wizard)))) and not in answers, it shows the question, but question goes first, so page is just reloaded.

Comment: I see. Well could it say that? It appears broken if it does nothing (also it appears not very useful in this light).

Comment: @theswine last activity shows last active part of your question - if it is question, it shows it and I don't see something strange in it...

Comment: @theswine however it can be really misleading to new users, I agree, and you can write a feature request to highlight question when it is the last activity, I can't do nothing about it :D

Comment: More things that will show the question when clicking the last active: bounty, reopening, and to top it all, Community Bump which is untraceable.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thx.